# Method call mActionBar=getActionBar() gives error

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-support-library

I am using support library `android.support.v7.app.actionbar` because i want action bar in **api level 8** and above 
But following sentence gives me error like change mActionBar to ActionBar

```
mActionBar=getActionBar();
```

My **FragmentActivity** in which I wnat to use **ActionBar** Tab is as follows

```
import com.example.bottomtabadapter.TabPageAdapter;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar.Tab;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.view.Menu;

public class TabFragmentActivity extends FragmentActivity implements ActionBar.TabListener{

private ViewPager mViewPager;
private ActionBar mActionBar;
private TabPageAdapter mAdapter;

private String[] tabs={"Chat","Groups","Contacts"};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_tab_fragment);

    mViewPager=(ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.pager);
    mActionBar=getActionBar();  // here is the error
    mAdapter=new TabPageAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.tab, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public void onTabReselected(Tab arg0, FragmentTransaction arg1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onTabSelected(Tab arg0, FragmentTransaction arg1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onTabUnselected(Tab arg0, FragmentTransaction arg1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
```

}

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/ActionBar.html before ask read it

Comment: did you extend activity or tabactivity

Comment: i think it is not runtime error but compile time error... ActionBar from support library != original ActionBar

Comment: if you can't answer for the question, please don't down grade for that questions

Comment: @Selvin I think this question should not be marked as off-topic, because the in the end it was resolved. I do agree that finding the root cause would have been easier with a posted logcat stacktrace though.

Comment: HemangNirmal, Kai duniya ma che bhai tu ?

Comment: And taro question off-topic kem kare che loko ??

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to have action bar for old devices from API 7 and up you should maybe extend [ActionBarActiviy](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/ActionBarActivity.html)

Comment: my class extends FragmentActivity and implements ActionBar.TabListener

Comment: You can just extend ActionBarActivity instead FragmentActivity.  Should not be a problem since ActionBarActivity extends FragmentActivity, see documentation

Comment: I just extend ActionBarActivity and now it works Thanks...

Comment: Excellent! Turns out that this question actually has an answer :-)

Comment: you didn't just extend ActionBarActivty , but you changed getActionBar to getSupportActionBar.

Answer (score 5):

try this code for  gingerbread.Don't forget to add supported library

```
public class NavigationActivity extends ActionBarActivity {


    ActionBarActivity activity;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.slide_screen);


         activity=(ActionBarActivity) Context.getApplicationContext();

        ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();

}
```

Comment: I try out ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar(); but it also gives me error

Comment: have you added supported library.check it in build path

Comment: @HemangNirmal change it to this - android.support.v7.app.ActionBar actionaBar = getSupportActionBar();